# Search IP from a text file in .csv log file, if found add new column next to it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, logging

I need a shell script that finds IP addresses from a text file inside a .csv log file, and if it found the results, it'll make a new column on the right side of the csv file, calling it "SUSPICIOUS"

So far, I came up with this command:

```
cat *.csv | grep --color=always -z -w -f 'list.txt' | sed 's/^/SUSPICIOUS, /' > *.csv
```

There are 2 problems with this:

1. It creates SUSPICIOUS column on every row
2. It creates new column on left side instead of right side

(If I use regular grep expression, it'll only save the results containing those IP addresses, I need every single row of the logs)

Comment: Redirecting output to `*.csv` is not right. You can only redirecet to one file at a time. You also can't redirect output to the same file that you're reading with `cat`.

Comment: Is the IP always in a particular field of the CSV file?

Comment: There will be only one file in the folder.... main script will import file to the folder and clear all these files out and move them to the server

Comment: IP is in the 8th column but i would like the script to search the whole thing if possible, just in case it appears on different columns

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would be much easier to do with `awk`. Load the text file into the keys of an associative array. Then read the CSV file, and test whether the IP field is contained in the array.

```
awk -i inplace -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR==FNR { a[$0]++; next } # Put lines from list.txt into array
    a[$8] { print $0 "SUSPICIOUS" } # Test if IP in current row is in array
    { print }' inplace=0 list.txt inplace=1 *.csv # Otherwise print row normally
```

This uses the inplace extension of GNU awk so it can write the result back to the input file.